# Ehcache not replicating between two tomcat on the same machine

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, caching, ehcache

I'm trying to set up a cache replication between two tomcat on the same machine. The cache works perfectly but the replication doesn't.

For my test, I call the count method on the server 1. Then I add an entity on server 2 and call the count method on server 2. Finally I call again the count method on server 1 : the cache is hit and my added entity is not found.

Tomcat version : 6, Java version : 1.6, Ehcache version : 1.3, OS : linux

Log at startup (same for both servers) :

```
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.LruMemoryStore for myCacheSample
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.LruMemoryStore - myCacheSample Cache: Using SpoolingLinkedHashMap implementation
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache - Initialised cache: myCacheSample
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener - Adding myCacheSample to RMI listener
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener - 0 RMICachePeers bound in registry for RMI listener
```

Code add :

```
public void persist(MyEntity myEntity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(myEntity);
}
```

Code count with cache setting :

```
public int count(String criteriaStr) {
    Criteria criteria = ((HibernateEntityManager) getEntityManager()).getSession().createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
    criteria.setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("myCacheSample");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("criteriaStr", criteriaStr));
    return (Integer) criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
}
```

Code remove:

```
public void remove(MyEntity myEntity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(myEntity);
    getEntityManager().flush();
}
```

Server 1 ehcache.xml (for server 2 : the ports 40001 and 40002 are switched) :

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
    rmiUrls=//localhost:40002/myCacheSample"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="
    hostName=localhost,
    port=40001,
    socketTimeoutMillis=2000
"/>

<defaultCache
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
    diskPersistent="false"
    eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    timeToIdleSeconds="120"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120">

<cacheEventListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
    properties="
        asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=1000,
        replicateAsynchronously=true,
        replicatePuts=false,
        replicateRemovals=true,
        replicateUpdates=true,
        replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false
    "/>

<cache
    eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    name="myCacheSample"
    overflowToDisk="false"/>
```

Thank you for answers !

Comment: does it works when the two tomcat are on different servers ?

Comment: No, but I'm not sure about the network administration (firewall, ports, etc). That's why I test on the same machine before, and not in multicast mode.

Answer (score 0):

Working configuration of RMI replication for 3 tomcat instances Hope it works for you.

```
    Server 1

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//localhost:40002/apicache|//localhost:40003/apicache" />

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="hostName=192.168.1.152, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=2000" />

Server 2        

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//localhost:40001/apicache|//localhost:40003/apicache" />

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="hostName=192.168.1.152, port=40002, socketTimeoutMillis=2000" />

Server 3

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//localhost:40001/apicache|//localhost:40002/apicache" />

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="hostName=192.168.1.152, port=40003, socketTimeoutMillis=2000" />
```